# How can I change the strings as variables in python django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to change the strings as variables. 
I have 7 models in Django.

```
class Level1:
   level1_id = models.IntegerField()
   level1_name = models.CharField()

class Level2:
   level2_id = models.IntegerField()
   level2_name = models.CharField()

class Level3:
   level3_id = models.IntegerField()
   level3_name = models.CharField()

class Level4:
   level4_id = models.IntegerField()
   level4_name = models.CharField()

class Level5:
   level5_id = models.IntegerField()
   level5_name = models.CharField()

class Level6:
   level6_id = models.IntegerField()
   level6_name = models.CharField()

class Level7:
   level7_id = models.IntegerField()
   level1_name = models.CharField()
```

I'm passing an integer 'level_id' in the range of 1-7 and 'name' via an AJAX request. Now in my views.py.

```
level_id = request.POST['level_id']
name = request.POST['name']

if level_id == 1:
    level_name = Level1.objects.all(level1_name = name)


if level_id == 2:
    level_name = Level2.objects.all(level2_name = name)


if level_id == 3:
    level_name = Level3.objects.all(level3_name = name)


if level_id == 4:
    level_name = Level4.objects.all(level4_name = name)


if level_id == 5:
    level_name = Level5.objects.all(level5_name = name)


if level_id == 6:
    level_name = Level6.objects.all(level6_name = name)


if level_id == 7:
    level_name = Level7.objects.all(level7_name = name)
```

Can I reduce all `if's` to make it more generc. Something like

```
dict = {"1":"Level1","2":"Level2","3":"Level3","4":"Level4","5":"Level5","6":"Level6","7":"Level7"}

level_name = dict[level_id].objects.all( dict[level_id]+"id" = name)
```

Comment: You rather reconsider your models. It seems that you can achieve same functionality using a single model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [django `get_model`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/loading.py) to your advantage here:

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model

level_id = request.POST['level_id']
name = request.POST['name']
model = get_model('app_name', 'Level%s' % level_id) #replace app_name with the app this model resides in.

params = {"level%s_name" % level_id: name}
level_name = model.objects.filter(**params)
```

I am not sure why you have

```
class Level1():
    level1_name = CharField()
```

You can just make it

```
class Level1():
    level_name = CharField()
```

That way you know which level it refers to.

Even better

```
class Level()
    level_name = CharField()
    level_id = IntegerField()
```

and get rid of `Level1`, `Level2`, ... This is more extendable

Comment: Does this app_name refers to the app in which my models.py is kept?